# Map right shift key to behave like top arrow

Tags: keyboard, mouse, magic-trackpad

guys I'm a software developer and I use arrows keys a lot. 
As long as Apple changed their keyboard layout it is so hard to use the new arrows setup. It' just drives me crazy every time when I try to go line up, or line down in my code editor.

Is there a way to map RIGHT SHIFT key to behave like a top ARROW ?
And map TOP ARROW key to behave like DOWN ARROW.

It would be a great solution for me. Thank you for your help. 
I've been trying to achieve this by Ukulele app, but I don't understand this app or I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Can you add what you've tried with Ukulele?

Comment: Anyway, from one of the popups within Ukulele: "If you want to make other modifications such as turning modifier keys into normal keys, or normal keys into modifier keys, Karabiner (https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) can likely help you.". So using Karabiner might be easier for this anyway.

Comment: I had to do the same re-mapping, with Karabiner. Was the only way I could survive in the past 3 years, otherwise it was impossible to program. – I'm not sure what kind of rotting brain bacteria they've got at Apple in the past years...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not heard of *Ukulele* and it wasn't in the top ten search results on DuckDuckGo.  So, allow me to recommend another third-party piece of software, which is open-source, well-established, powerful, reasonably intuitive, and widely known and popular in its use with developers and *"power users"*.

[**Karabiner Elements**](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) is stable in and updated for macOS Catalina.

Most keyboard mappings will be achieved using the GUI in a pretty straight-forward interface.  For complex mappings, there's a configuration file you can edit which uses `JSON` ([Karabiner `.json` Reference Manual](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/json.html)).

Yours are classified as *simple modifications*, e.g. <kbd>`⇧ᴿ`</kbd> `⥱` <kbd>↑</kbd>, so can be created straight in the GUI. [Here's a screenshot series](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/document.html#configuration-simple-modifications) that shows how intuitive it is.

Comment: Ukulele is here: http://software.sil.org/ukelele/

Comment: Bro this soft is awesome, you just saved me from spending 100$ for a new keyboard :) Good bless you!

Comment: The makers of _Karabiner_ don't charge for it, but should you feel giving, their website has a page that allows you to donate whatever amount you wish to help support development and open source software.